# Symfony exception with 403 http status in kernel request listener

Tags: events, symfony, listener

I have a Symfony2 app, with two bundles - AppBundle and UserBundle. I created kernel.request event listener in UserBundle. How can I throw AccessDeniedException exception with http status code 403(Forbidden) in onKernelRequest method? I will check user access to controller/action and if user has restriction then I will throw this exception.

```
<?php

namespace Company\AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class CompanyRequestListener
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('Access Denied');
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Google and Documentation helps... http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/securing_services.html

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you looking for are not events, but [custom security voters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html).

Comment: Gah, just spent a while there exending `EntityUserProvider` to do some actions based on a logged in user's attributes. It worked (sorta, I can only trigger a 401 when I want 403). This looks a lot more on the money!